# Getting error while installing package to anaconda3-2018 on Redhat 6(RHEL 6)

Tags: anaconda

We have anaconda version as “anaconda3-2018” in our environment. Due to security vulnerabilities, we were removing pyspark, sqlalchemy, requests forcefully because conda remove was not working while trying to remove below packages.
/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/bin/conda remove --force-remove pyspark
/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/bin/conda remove --force-remove sqlalchemy
/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/bin/conda remove --force-remove requests
After removing above packages we were not able to install any package to anaconda3-2018. We are planning to install “gensim-3.4.0-py37h14c3975_0.tar.bz2” , “pytorch-1.0.1-cuda92py37h65efead_0.tar.bz2” and “linux-64/gensim-3.4.0-py37h14c3975_0.tar.bz2”For anything we were facing below errors. Please suggest
[root@l51hdvmi-03 pbibhu]# /opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/bin/conda install pytorch-1.0.1-cuda92py37h65efead_0.tar.bz2

## >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from requests import ConnectionError, HTTPError, Session
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1003, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 80, in do_call
    module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .install import install
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..core.index import calculate_channel_urls, get_index
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/path_actions.py", line 31, in <module>
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests import ConnectionError, HTTPError, Session
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 94, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.compat import WINDOWS
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._internal.download import PipSession
  File "/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/download.py", line 325, in <module>
    class PipSession(requests.Session):
AttributeError: module 'pip._vendor.requests' has no attribute 'Session'
```

`$ /opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/bin/conda install pytorch-1.0.1-cuda92py37h65efead_0.tar.bz2`
  environment variables:
            CASP_BIN_PATH=/opt/CA/UnicenterNSM/bin
            CASP_LIB_PATH=/opt/CA/UnicenterNSM/lib
                CASP_PATH=/opt/CA/UnicenterNSM
           CA_DIA_JREPATH=/opt/CA/SharedComponents/JRE/1.7.0_25
                 CIO_TEST=
               CONDA_ROOT=/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018
          LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/CA/SharedComponents/lib:/opt/CA/CAlib:/opt/CA/SharedComponents/Cs
                          am/SockAdapter/lib:/usr/lib:/opt/CA/UnicenterNSM/lib:/opt/CA/SharedCom
                          ponents/ccs/dia/lib:/opt/CA/SharedComponents/ccs/dia/dna/lib:/opt/CA/S
                          haredComponents/JRE/1.7.0_25/lib/i386:/opt/CA/SharedComponents/JRE/1.7
                          .0_25/lib/i386/client
                     PATH=/usr/local/git/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr
                          /local/git/bin:/opt/CA/SharedComponents/bin:/opt/CA/SharedComponents/c
                          cs/cam/bin:/opt/CA/SharedComponents/ccs/atech/services/bin:/opt/CA/Sha
                          redComponents/ccs/atech/agents/bin:/opt/CA/SharedComponents/ccs/bin:/o
                          pt/CA/SharedComponents/ccs/scripts:/opt/CA/SharedComponents/ccs/snmp/b
                          in:/opt/CA/UnicenterNSM/nsmutils/bin:/opt/CA/UnicenterNSM/bin:/root/bi
                          n
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=
            SSL_CERT_FILE=
             SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/bash
                 SUDO_GID=13000
                 SUDO_UID=14272
                SUDO_USER=pbibhu

```
 active environment : None
   user config file : /root/.condarc
```

populated config files :
          conda version : 4.6.14
    conda-build version : 3.17.6
         python version : 3.7.1.final.0
       base environment : /opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/pkgs
                          /root/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/envs
                          /root/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.14 requests/2.19.1 CPython/3.7.1 Linux/2.6.32-754.9.1.el6.x86_64 rhel/6.10 glibc/2.12
                UID:GID : 0:0
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
[y/N]:
Timeout reached. No report sent.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter nearly the same issue when installing packages offline with Anaconda. Seems that PATH variable is polluted. The following is my resolution on Ubuntu 16.04:

- First, check ~/.bashrc to make sure your PATH is set correcly.
- Then, execute: `$ PATH=$(getconf PATH)` to reset PATH variable
- Now, go to your anaconda3 folder (/opt/cloudera/extras/anaconda3-2018/bin) and execute: `$ ./conda init` so anaconda could fix its paths in your .bashrc file.
- Finally, execute: `$ source ~/.bashrc`